# Assign specific value based on two column in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe which looks like:

```
   Student_ID    Number  Position
    VB-123        10      2
    VB-456        15      5
    VB-789        25      25
    VB-889        12      2
    VB-965        15      7
    VB-758        45      9
    VB-245        25      25
```

I want to add new column and assign a value based on below conditions:

1. If only `Number` is duplicate in entire dataframe then Assign `A`
2. If only `Position` is duplicate in entire dataframe then assign `B`
3. If both `Number` and `Position` are duplicate then assign `C`
4. If none of the duplicate then assign `D`.

Output would looks like:

```
Student_ID    Number  Position   Assign
    VB-123        10      2      B
    VB-456        15      5      A
    VB-789        25      25     C
    VB-889        12      2      B
    VB-965        15      7      A
    VB-758        45      9      D
    VB-245        25      25     C
```

Comment: ideally, if you could post your data frame as code, this would help us. A way to transform your data frame into code is dput() or you make a dummy data frame (often better, because you reduce your data to the essential ...)

Comment: @Tjebo le voilà: https://alistaire47.github.io/read.so/

Comment: @alistaire Brilliant! That is really cool. Cheers!

Comment: @alistaire Superb....:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an option using `base R`.  Create a `list` of column names as in the order of evaluatin ('l1'), pre assign 'D' to create the 'Assign' column in 'dat', loop through the sequence of 'l1', subset the columns of data based on the column names in 'l1', use `duplicated` to find the duplicate elements and reassign the 'Assign' column to the corresponding `LETTER`

```
l1 <- list("Number", "Position", c("Number", "Position"))
dat$Assign <- rep("D", nrow(dat))
for(i in seq_along(l1)){
    df <- dat[l1[[i]]]  
    i1 <- duplicated(df)|duplicated(df, fromLast = TRUE)
    dat$Assign <- replace(dat$Assign, i1, LETTERS[i])
}
```

-output

```
dat
#  Student_ID Number Position Assign
#1     VB-123     10        2      B
#2     VB-456     15        5      A
#3     VB-789     25       25      C
#4     VB-889     12        2      B
#5     VB-965     15        7      A
#6     VB-758     45        9      D
#7     VB-245     25       25      C
```

Answer (score 3):

With dplyr,

```r
library(dplyr)

students <- data.frame(Student_ID = c("VB-123", "VB-456", "VB-789", "VB-889", "VB-965", "VB-758", "VB-245"), 
                       Number = c(10L, 15L, 25L, 12L, 15L, 45L, 25L), 
                       Position = c(2L, 5L, 25L, 2L, 7L, 9L, 25L))

students2 <- students %>% 
    mutate_at(vars(Number, Position), funs(n = table(.)[as.character(.)])) %>% 
    mutate(Assign = case_when(Number_n > 1 & Position_n > 1 ~ 'C', 
                              Number_n > 1 ~ 'A', 
                              Position_n > 1 ~ 'B', 
                              TRUE ~ 'D'))

students2
#>   Student_ID Number Position Number_n Position_n Assign
#> 1     VB-123     10        2        1          2      B
#> 2     VB-456     15        5        2          1      A
#> 3     VB-789     25       25        2          2      C
#> 4     VB-889     12        2        1          2      B
#> 5     VB-965     15        7        2          1      A
#> 6     VB-758     45        9        1          1      D
#> 7     VB-245     25       25        2          2      C
```

As an alternative to the `mutate_at` line, you could use `add_count` twice, renaming as necessary. To remove the intermediary columns, tack on `select(-matches('_n$'))`.

You can more or less replicate the logic in base by assigning to subsets:

```r
students2 <- cbind(students, lapply(students[2:3], function(x) table(x)[as.character(x)]))
students2$Assign <- 'D'
students2$Assign[students2$Number.Freq > 1 & students2$Position.Freq > 1] <- 'C'
students2$Assign[students2$Number.Freq > 1 & students2$Position.Freq == 1] <- 'A'
students2$Assign[students2$Number.Freq == 1 & students2$Position.Freq > 1] <- 'B'
students2[4:7] <- NULL

students2
#>   Student_ID Number Position Assign
#> 1     VB-123     10        2      B
#> 2     VB-456     15        5      A
#> 3     VB-789     25       25      C
#> 4     VB-889     12        2      B
#> 5     VB-965     15        7      A
#> 6     VB-758     45        9      D
#> 7     VB-245     25       25      C
```

Comment: a small issue here in column `Position` i have some alpha numeric value (somewhere in upper case & somewhere in lowercase) like "a2$" and "A2$", these code didn't work there. Please suggest how to take care those.

Comment: How does it fail? `table` is case-sensitive, and `x <- c('a2$', 'A2$', 'a2$'); table(x)[as.character(x)]` works, so I'm not sure why/how it'd fail. Or are you saying they should be the same? If so, convert them with `toupper`/`tolower`—temporarily, if you like.

Answer (score 1):

A solution using [dplyr](/questions/tagged/dplyr).

```
library(dplyr)

dat2 <- dat %>% count(Number)
dat3 <- dat %>% count(Position)
dat4 <- dat %>% count(Number, Position)

dat5 <- dat %>%
  left_join(dat2, by = "Number") %>%
  left_join(dat3, by = "Position") %>%
  left_join(dat4, by = c("Number", "Position")) %>%
  mutate(Assign = case_when(
    n > 1               ~ "C",
    n.x > 1 & n.y == 1  ~ "A",
    n.y > 1 & n.x == 1  ~ "B",
    TRUE                ~ "D"
  )) %>%
  select(-n.x, -n.y, -n)
dat5
#   Student_ID Number Position Assign
# 1     VB-123     10        2      B
# 2     VB-456     15        5      A
# 3     VB-789     25       25      C
# 4     VB-889     12        2      B
# 5     VB-965     15        7      A
# 6     VB-758     45        9      D
# 7     VB-245     25       25      C
```

**DATA**

```
dat <- read.table(text = "Student_ID    Number  Position
    'VB-123'        10      2
    'VB-456'        15      5
    'VB-789'        25      25
    'VB-889'        12      2
    'VB-965'        15      7
    'VB-758'        45      9
    'VB-245'        25      25",
                  header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: How i can take care of alpha numeric value (either in upper case or in lower case like `a$2` and `A$2` in `Position` column.

Comment: @Roy1245 Dealing with characters is different than dealing with numbers. I would suggest to ask a new question. This time, provide a reproducible example with alpha numeric values so that people know the true structure of your data frame.

Comment: I have only around 3% cases where alpha numeric value are present.

Comment: OK. Perhaps use `toupper` to convert all your alpha numeric values to upper case and then use one of the three solutions here.